# Openlayers get the image url of the tile under the mouse

Tags: openlayers

I am looking to get the image url of the tile under the mouse.

Using the newest version v4.6.4

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tile source classes have all the information about the tile grid: `tileSource.getTileGrid()`
You can access it's [loader function](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html#getTileUrlFunction) and pass coordinate, ratio and projection to it.

```js
const source = new ol.source.OSM();
const layer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source });
const view = new ol.View({
  center: [2500000, 0], zoom: 5
});
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [ layer,
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileDebug({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        tileGrid: source.getTileGrid()
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view 
});

const tileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction();
map.on('click', function(event) {
 const grid = source.getTileGrid();
 const tileCord = grid.getTileCoordForCoordAndZ(event.coordinate, view.getZoom());
 console.log('clicked ', event.coordinate[0], event.coordinate[1]);
 console.log('tile z,x,y is:', tileCord[0],tileCord[1], tileCord[2]);
 console.log(tileUrlFunction(tileCord, 1, ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857')));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Would you happen to know how to get the _relative_ (within the found Tile) x and y of the pixel clicked?

Comment: I found TileGrid.getTileCoordExtent, which does the job coupled to some pixel arithmetic