# How to download, store and load tiles using Open Layers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, openlayers

I'm creating a PWA using Open Layers. The user must have an option to download the Tiles on the Wifi to load them Offline. I read the Open Layers documentation, but, I couldn't find the answer for my problem. The section [Tile Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) is empty.

Comment: OpenLayers 2 had built-in caching to localStorage http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/offline-storage.html  For caching to sessionStorage or localStorage in more recent versions see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607810/how-to-download-the-osm-tiles-for-selected-part-of-map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need three things for this to work:

1. An IndexedDB to store tiles
2. A custom `tileLoadFunction` for your tile source
3. A component that downloads tiles for a given extent

For (1), you'll want to set up a store, e.g. `tiles`. The snippet below uses the idb package (https://npmjs.com/package/idb):

```js
import idb from 'idb';

let indexedDb;

idb.open(this.name, 1, upgradeDb => {
  if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('tiles')) {
    upgradeDb.createObjectStore('tiles');
  }
}).then(db => {
  indexedDb = db;
});
```

For (2), a starting point could look something like this:

```js
source.setTileLoadFunction(function(tile, url) {
  const tx = db.transaction('tiles', 'readonly');
  tiles = tx.objectStore('tiles');
  const image = tile.getImage();

  tiles.get(url).then(blob => {
    if (!blob) {
      // use online url
      image.src = url;
      return;
    }
    const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    image.onload = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(objUrl);
    };
    image.src = objUrl;
  }).catch(() => {
    // use online url
    image.src = url;
  });
}
```

For (3), you'll probably want to limit downloading to a small extent. Then, for the chosen `extent` (in map units) and each `zoom` level you want to cache, do something like this:

```js
const tilegrid = source.getTileGrid();
const projection = map.getView().getProjection();
const getUrl = source.getTileUrlFunction();
tilegrid.forEachTileCoord(extent, zoom, tilecoord => {
  const url = getUrl(tilecoord, devicePixelRatio, projection);
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      response.blob().then(blob => {
        const tx = db.transaction('tiles', 'readwrite');
        const tiles = tx.objectStore('tiles');
        tiles.put(url, blob);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just have one more question: Is there a limit to the data that I can put on the IndexDB?

Comment: Yes, there are limits, and those depend on several factors. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350531/2389327.